# Is this idiomatically service classes passing (server side), for Ktor app (no Koin or Dagger)?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, jvm, microservices, ktor

My question is, how I should **idiomatically** pass my `Service` classes to `Application` modules?

```kotlin
fun Application.myPlugin() {
    routing {
        post("/do") {
            val result = this@myPlugin.myService.do()
            call.respond(result)
        }
    }
}

val Application.myService get() = MyService(this)

class MyService(private val app: Application) {
    fun do() { 
        app.environment.config.property("app.my-prop").getString() 
    }
}
```